# sqlite3.OperationalError, near "<": syntax error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3, discord-api

Сделал функцию, которая возвращает префикс для бота, взятый из базы, однако при запуске получаю ошибку:

`sqlite3.OperationalError, near "<": syntax error`

Код:

```
def prefix(gid: int):
    db.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM settings WHERE gid={gid}")
    prefix = db.fetchone()
    if prefix:
        prefix = list(prefix)[0][0]
        return prefix
```

По правде, я не совсем понимаю откуда взялся `<`

Comment: это неверная работа с бд

Comment: Добавьте в код перехват исключения и в блоке `except` выводите на экран значение `gid`. На все 100% уверен, что в нём будет не число.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [параметризованные запросы (PEP-0249)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), для того чтобы избежать SQL Injections и чтобы сделать ваш код более устойчивым к ошибкам и более гибким (Python сам позаботиться о том, чтобы обрамить строки кавычками и т.д.):

```
db.execute("SELECT prefix FROM settings WHERE gid=?", (gid,))
```